# Magento 2 with Gatsby and GraphQl issue

Tags: module, javascript, magento2.3.2, graphql, npm

I am trying to integrate the magento2.3.2 with gatsby js and Graphql. For reference please check this link https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-magento2/

I have integrated everything but I get the below issue of

```
UNHANDLED REJECTION The "time" argument must be of type Array. Received type number



  Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "time" argument must be of type Array. Received type number

  - per_thread.js:105 process.hrtime
    internal/process/per_thread.js:105:15

  - index.js:174 Object.end
    [react-moto]/[gatsby]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/reporter/index.js:174:54

  - products.js:162 
    [react-moto]/[gatsby-source-magento2]/nodes/products.js:162:16

  - Generator.next
```

on running this command `gatsby develop`

Comment: post your graphql shema pls

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved here:
https://github.com/mobelop/gatsby-source-magento2/issues/2
There is also a PR about it.

You need to add this after line 47 in /nodes/products.js

```
activity.start();
```

I tried it now and it works.